# Retrieving a value from XML based on query parameter?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the following XML file, generated by my Windows Phone 8 app.

All works so far, but now I'd like to be able to query the file, and retrieve the  associated with a particular  -- So if I query it against "2222 it" would return "Location Name".

I have tried a few ways of doing this but I realised i didnt have a clue how to achieve this, even after hours of research. XML and LINQ confuse me immeasurably....so I woul really appreciate any tutorials or tips anyone could offer! Code thus far is below the sample XML document.

Thank you very much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SmartSafe>
  <Tag>
    <tag>22222</tag>
    <name>Location Name</name>
    <latitude>xx.xxxxxxx</latitude>
    <longitude>xx.xxxxxxx</longitude>
  </Tag>
  <Tag>
    <tag>4444</tag>
    <name>Location Name</name>
    <latitude>xx.xxxxxxx</latitude>
    <longitude>xx.xxxxxxx</longitude>
  </Tag>
  <Tag>
    <tag>4444</tag>
    <name>Location Name</name>
    <latitude>xx.xxxxxxx</latitude>
    <longitude>xx.xxxxxxx</longitude>
  </Tag>
  <Tag>
    <tag>4444</tag>
    <name>Location Name</name>
    <latitude>xx.xxxxxxx</latitude>
    <longitude>xx.xxxxxxx</longitude>
  </Tag>
</SmartSafe>
```

Below is the section of the .cs which handles parsing the uid passed from the UriAssociationMapper.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("uid"))
    {
        uid = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["uid"]);
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    string stringUid = uid.ToString();
    tagID.Text = stringUid;

    //Retrieve tag name from xml

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    XDocument document;
    using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        if (storage.FileExists("/tagRegistry.xml"))
        {
            using (var stream = storage.OpenFile("/tagRegistry.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                document = XDocument.Load(stream);
            }
        }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ to XML query should look like that:

```
var value = doc.Root.Elements("Tag")
                    .FirstOrDefault(t => (string)t.Element("tag") == "22222")
                    .Element("name").Value;
```

However, It will throw `NullReferenceException` if element is not found, so you shouldn't use it if you're not sure XML document contains what you're looking for. If you're not sure about that, you should probably use following instead:

```
var tag = doc.Root.Elements("Tag")
                  .FirstOrDefault(t => (string)t.Element("tag") == "22222");

var value = tag == null ? string.Empty : (string)tag.Element("name");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

The NullReferenceException handler is much appreciated too.